# Find Information about debian package located in a particular directory

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have some debian packages not located in my default debian directory. I know I can find the information of packages located in my default debian directory as follows:

```
dpkg-query -W package-name
```

Is there a way to find the details of a debian package **not** located in the default debian directory?

(I tried searching for a command line option on the `dpkg-query` and `apt-cache` man pages but no luck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

```
dpkg --info  package_name
```

it will give you details like Architecture,Dependencies ,Version etc. 
for example

```
dpkg --info  teamviewer_linux.deb


new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 43331378 bytes: control archive=1478 bytes.
    1015 bytes,    17 lines      control              
     695 bytes,    40 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/bash
     595 bytes,    42 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/bash
      18 bytes,     3 lines   *  preinst              #!/bin/bash
     989 bytes,    45 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/bash
 Package: teamviewer
 Version: 10.0.35002
 Section: non-free/internet
 Priority: optional
 Architecture: i386
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1, libasound2, libfontconfig1, libfreetype6, libjpeg8 | libjpeg62, libpng12-0, libsm6, libxdamage1, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxrandr2, libxrender1, libxtst6, zlib1g
 Recommends: ttf-liberation | fonts-liberation
 Replaces: teamviewer5, teamviewer6, teamviewer7, teamviewer8, teamviewer9
 Conflicts: teamviewer5, teamviewer6, teamviewer7, teamviewer8, teamviewer9
 Installed-Size: 122640
 Maintainer: Teamviewer GmbH <service@teamviewer.com>
 Description: TeamViewer (Remote Control Application)
  TeamViewer is a remote control application. TeamViewer provides easy, fast and secure remote access to Linux, Windows PCs, and Macs.
  .
  TeamViewer is free for personal use. You can use TeamViewer completely free of charge to access your private computers or to help your friends with their computer problems.
  .
  To buy a license for commercial use, please visit http://www.teamviewer.com
```